# What could be causing "no action" state?

Tags: bazel

I have a Bazel repo that builds some artifact. The problem is that it stops half way through hanging with this message:

```
[3 / 8] no action
```

What on the earth could be causing this condition? Is this normal?

(No, the problem is not easily reducible, there is a lot of custom code and if I could localize the issue, I'd not be writing this question. I'm interested in general answer, what in principle could cause this and is this normal.)

Comment: What platform are you running Bazel on?

Comment: @László, Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer your question without more information, but yes it is sometimes normal. Bazel does several things that are not actions.

One reason that I've seen this is if Bazel is computing digests of lots of large files. If you see `getDigestInExclusiveMode` in the stack trace of the Bazel server, it is likely due to this. If this is your problem, you can try out the `--experimental_multi_threaded_digest` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the platform you are running Bazel on:

- **Windows**: I've seen similar behavior, but I couldn't yet determine the reason. Every few runs, Bazel hangs at the startup for about half a minute.

  If this is mid-build during execution phase (as it appears to be, given that Bazel is already printing action status messages), then one possible explanation is that your build contains many shell commands. I measured that on Linux (a VM with an HDD) each shell command takes at most 1-2ms, but on my Windows 10 machine (32G RAM, 3.5GHz CPU, HDD) they take 1-2 seconds, with 0.5% of the commands taking up to 10 seconds. That's 3-4 orders of magnitude slower if your actions are heavy on shell commands. There can be numerous explanations for this (antivirus, slow process creation, MSYS being slow), none of which Bazel has control over.
- **Linux/macOS**: Run `top` and see if the stuck Bazel process is doing anything at all. Try hitting Ctrl+\, that'll print a JVM stacktrace which could help identifying the problem. Maybe the JVM is stuck waiting in a lock -- that would mean a bug or a bad rule implementation.

There are other possibilities too, maybe you have a build rule that hangs.

Does Bazel eventually continue, or is it stuck for more than a few minutes?